# How to update without creating a whole new field using upsert in mongodb golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

Okay, so. There is this field called bitfield and inside is a map. Everytime i set bits, for example set bit 5000, i'll get key 4096, but if i set bit 1000, then i'll get the key, just 0. However, i set both, 5000 and 0, so it should be both keys 0 and 4096. How can i update the existing field, without deleting the other data, so both keys 0 and 4096 exist?

```
func UpsertBitsArray(tx models.Transactions, sendingQrlAddress string) (error, string) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    optionss := options.Find().
        SetProjection(bson.M{"bitfield": 1}).
        SetLimit(1)

    results, err := addressesCollections.Find(ctx, bson.M{"id": sendingQrlAddress}, optionss)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, "Success"
    }

    var bitfieldStruct []wallet.Wallet
    err = results.All(ctx, &bitfieldStruct)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, "Success"
    }

    // signature, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(tx.Signature)
    // if err != nil {
    //  glog.Info("%v", err)
    // }
    otsKeyIndex := big.NewInt(10000)

    for _, bitfieldExist := range bitfieldStruct {
        if bitfieldExist.Paged == nil {
            fmt.Println("No array/bitfield, creating new one..")
            bitfieldExist.Paged = bitfield.NewBig()
            bitfieldExist.Paged.Set(otsKeyIndex)
            filter := bson.D{{"id", sendingQrlAddress}}
            update := bson.D{
                {
                    Key: "$set",
                    Value: bson.D{
                        {Key: "bitfield", Value: bitfieldExist.Paged},
                    },
                },
            }
            opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(true)
            result, err := addressesCollections.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update, opts)
            if err != nil {
                glog.Info("%v", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Number of documents updated: %v\n", result.ModifiedCount)
            fmt.Printf("Number of documents upserted: %v\n", result.UpsertedCount)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Bitfield/array exists, setting it..")
            bitfieldExist.Paged.Set(otsKeyIndex)
            filter := bson.D{{"id", sendingQrlAddress}}
            update := bson.D{
                {
                    Key: "$set",
                    Value: bson.D{
                        {Key: "bitfield", Value: bitfieldExist.Paged},
                    },
                },
            }
            opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(true)
            result, err := addressesCollections.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update, opts)
            if err != nil {
                glog.Info("%v", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Number of documents updated: %v\n", result.ModifiedCount)
            fmt.Printf("Number of documents upserted: %v\n", result.UpsertedCount)
        }
    }

    return nil, "Success"
}
```

Here is what i mean:
[image]

[image]

Edit:

The wallet struct:

```
type Wallet struct {
    _id    primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id,omitempty"`
    Id     string             `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Amount int                `json:"amount,omitempty"`
    Paged  bitfield.Big       `json:"bitfield"`
}
```

What i'm storing:

```
package bitfield

import (
    "math/big"
)

const (
    fieldSize = 1024
)

type Big map[string]Bitfield

func NewBig() Big {
    return make(map[string]Bitfield)
}

func (fields Big) Set(i *big.Int) {
    number, pageNumber := indexOfBig(i, fieldSize)

    page, exists := fields[pageNumber.String()]
    if !exists {
        page = New(fieldSize)
        fields[pageNumber.String()] = page

    }

    page.Set(uint(number.Uint64()))
}
```

Comment: Could you try to create a complete example where this behavior is present? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve from the code above.

Comment: Do you mean the code of bitfield.NewBig() and             bitfieldExist.Paged.Set(otsKeyIndex)? What i'm trying to achieve is setting bits. The bits are on certain "pages". The code above shows that i load the bitfield field data and then create a new one if it doesn't exist and set the bits. If it does exist, i only set the bits.

Comment: You have bunch of custom structs here and no definition.

Comment: I added the wallet.Wallet struct